# why granule = true is causing exception on page load?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

when `granule = true`,

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
```

if `granule = false`, working fine

Comment: what would be possible root cause? because it was not coming before. updating few js produced the issue –

Comment: Probably the JS you have updated now have a unique ID within Granule cache, you would need to post the changes you have done. What is the size of your cache folder ?

Answer (score 1):

increasing jvm stack memory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is from a legacy code. They used it before and now it is not supported by its developers and hybris. For more reference: [Hybris wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/Go-live+-+Hybris+Application+Server+Considerations)

Comment: what would be possible root cause? because it was not coming before. updating few js produced the issue